# i cannot access to file content on public disk

Tags: laravel, permissions, storage, file-permissions

On Laravel 8

```
file_get_contents(asset('storage/list.json');
```

Give me:

> ErrorException
> file_get_contents(http://localhost:8000/storage/list.json): failed to
> open stream: HTTP request failed!

But: `http://localhost:8000/storage/list.json` exist and it is accesible via browser for example.
On my `config/filesystem.php` iv'e:

```
'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
            'permissions' => [
                        'file' => [
                            'public' => 0664,
                            'private' => 0600,
                        ],
                        'dir' => [
                            'public' => 0775,
                            'private' => 0700,
                        ],
                        ],
            ],
        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

And ive created the symbolic link with:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

command.

I've tried even to add manually file perssion to storage folder as described in the filesystem.php but nothing change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use absolute paths when you want to work with files. file_get_contents() is fine. There are some file wrappers available in laravel but internally they all use file_get_contents().

Try

```
file_get_contents(public_path(asset('storage/list.json')));
```

If getting from storage file try

```
file_get_contents(storage_path('app/assets/list.json'));
```

See https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-resource-path

Comment: the thing thats make it works is add "'app/public/" before "storage" in the firts case that you suggest, ok thats they like absolute path, but to me is so strange that a thing that is even accessible via http isnt in local! thanks a lot 'file_get_contents(storage_path('app/public/list.json'));'

Comment: if you can access `http://localhost:8000/storage/list.json` it means that your application is not secured. This means people can access your storage and public directory. Donot set folder permission of storage to 777 just because it is easier in production or local.

Comment: as described the file permission are setted in "config/filesystem.php" but so it seems thats def not works and not picking folder permission and structure too!

Comment: you will need to do it using ssh or from command line.